# How to find roots for $y = ||x^2-x-20|-8|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

$$
y = ||x^2-x-20|-8|
$$

After I set $y = 0$, I do not know how to deal with multiple absolute values.

Comment: Note that the absolute value of something equals $0$ _if and only if_ the thing inside equals $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$|x^2-x-20|-8=0$$
$$\iff |x^2-x-20|=8$$
$$\iff x^2-x-20=\pm 8$$
$$\iff x^2-x-20-8=0\ \text{or}\ x^2-x-20+8=0$$

Answer (score 2):

$$y = ||x^2-x-20|-8|$$

Setting $y=0$ we have the following:

$$||x^2-x-20|-8|=0 \Rightarrow |x^2-x-20|-8=0 \Rightarrow |x^2-x-20|=8 \Rightarrow x^2-x-20=\pm 8 $$